# Maintain motivation for new members

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

While looking through old questions I noticed the majority of questions is answered by around a dozen of people. 
New questions reach a stunning short answering time, which makes it difficult for Newbies to stack up reputation by answering questions. 
While I really admire the passion and afford the pros put into answering questions, I think this could scare off Newbies. Even if new users answer a question, people tend to upvote answers by people with a higher reputation - which are often better, to be fair.

Do we have any way to encourage new users to answer questions?

Comment: This is true and even for higher rep users the answers are not upvoted as much as the highest rep users. The point is that we have a highly experienced community whose members know how to provide the correct answer, because many questions are basically duplicates or quite connected to them.

Comment: Please consider also the fact that there are a lot of users who just want to have an answer to their own question and don't care about giving feedback/upvotes/accepts or contribute to the community otherwise by own posts, neither on the main site nor  here on meta.

Comment: I thought of this. Maybe it's just a side effect since the TeX community seems to be more dense and smaller than others

Comment: Well, although I have accounts on some other SE sites I am active only here and I can't compare really, but I think you're right about the size of the TeX community (here and outside in the huge world)

Comment: In my point of view this question was closed too early

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I accepted the duplicate, since the Question pointed out has the exact same goal as this one. Though a little more discussion would be great ;)

Comment: Well, we tried on Chat, but I had the impression, we were the only ones talking about/discussing it -- the same like here ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Is there a problem with the closure of this question? I think it's a clear duplicate, and has been indicated as such by the OP.

Comment: @Werner: More discussion would have been nice, that's all I wanted to state. I had no idea that the other question exists